# Storing data for querying by date range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, date, memcached, schema

I'm trying to store a lot of data (30 years worth of daily prices) in MySQL and want to query them by daily, monthly, yearly.

I know I can use aggregate functions on indexed date fields and this will also be cached by MySQL itself, but I'm not sure if it might be expensive. I've also thought about storing monthly and yearly data separately but I'm pretty sure this is against normalization rules and will be difficult to maintain.

If it's expensive, I'm planning to add memcached in. I just want to get some feedback and I'm sure this has been done time and time again. Any best practices for this particular problem?

**Update:**

Just to provide more detail, the data will be shown in a chart that can be easily adjusted by daily, weekly, monthly, yearly ranges. It's still currently in development and I don't have enough data to determine optimization requirements. If that's the case, do you think I should defer optimization until I see the problem? (probably premature optimization?) Or is there a base line pattern to prepare for this kind of problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The database structure should be driven by the requirements for accessing the data.  Your question does not explain what the actual access patterns are.

If you have performance requirements for monthly and yearly summaries, and the 30-years worth of daily records that are too detailed, then you can maintain summaries in the database.  The complexity is the addition of logic, in either stored procedures or triggers, to maintain the summary tables.

This is a common structure for meeting performance needs.

You may be able to achieve your needs with some clever data structures.  You question does not give enough information about what you really need.  Perhaps table partitioning can solve the performance issue.  Perhaps having separate, indexable columns for year and month can solve the problem.  Perhaps having flags that indicate high-and-low values for a month or year can solve the problem (although you would need triggers to maintain these).

Comment: I've updated my question with a little detail. I know it's still not much, but thanks for the suggestions. I'm leaning towards having just the separate indexed columns for year and month.